# App crashs in drawViewHierarchyInRect

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uiimageview, screenshot, xcode8

My app is used large images (5MB) to markup. But app is getting crashed without any error messages.
Below is the code I used

```
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(_drawingUV.drawingImgView.image.size.width, _drawingUV.drawingImgView.image.size.height));
        {
                CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

            if ([_drawingUV.drawingImgView respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)])
            {
                [_drawingUV.drawingImgView drawViewHierarchyInRect:_drawingUV.drawingImgView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
            }
            else
            {
                [_drawingUV.drawingImgView.layer renderInContext:context];
            }
            screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I have tried all possibilities to find a solution last two days. But could not.

This function is used below UI objects.
main view has view and inside that it has UIScrollView and inside that UIScrollView has UIImageView. So I need to get screenshoto this UIImageView. I use these views to scroll and markup the the image view.
 Any idea for this crash?

Comment: Have you tried removing the outer braces "{..}" ? Also, do you really need to support `renderInContext` (iOS 6 and below)?

Comment: Yes. I tried. renderInContext can be removed. this imageview  can be scrollabled and image Height = 6000 and Width = 6000+.

Answer (score 0):

I use this all the time without issue:

```
- (UIImage *)screenshot {
    UIWindow *mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mainWindow.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
    [mainWindow drawViewHierarchyInRect:mainWindow.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Here you are getting main screen screenshot. I want to get imageview screenshot. And this image view can be scrollabled and image Height = 6000 and Width = 6000+.

Comment: I have tested it with a UIImageView 6000x6000 and it works fine on the simulator. Bear in mind the memory required just to store a 6Kx6K image is 144MB - Xcode's memory usage monitor peaked at over 1GB while it was rendering the view hierarchy.